# Django conditional order by with many to many field

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, many-to-many

I need conditional ordering in django but don't know how to do it.

I have two models: `User` and `Post`. `Post` model have `seen_users = ManyToManyField(User)` field.

I want to get all posts, but my seen posts should be at first.

I've tried with this code:

```
Post.objects.all().annotate(
        is_seen=Case(
            When(seen_users__id__exact=me.id, then=1),
            default=0,
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    ).order_by('-is_seen', '-created')
```

but this one returns duplicated posts. I tried to add `distinct` but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what I understand you're after an ordered collection of posts that are seen and posts that are not seen. You could accomplish this in the following way.

The single underscore in `seen_users_id` for id is not a typo. You can access the id without joining the tables which will end up being a more efficient query.

```
seen = Posts.objects.filter(
    seen_users_id=me.id
).order_by('-created')

not_seen = Posts.objects.exclude(
    seen_users_id=me.id
).order_by('-created')

posts = list(seen) + list(not_seen)
```

So this solves your problem but with two queries. You might try to use the union which is supported by the orm to just make it one query.

```
all_posts = lists(seen.union(not_seen))
```

The above will only make one roundtrip to the database. But you'll probably have to annotate the two queries to differentiate between and not seen. But it shouldn't show any duplicates.

Comment: So there is no way to do it with one query?

Comment: @Bulgantamir Added some more explanation how it could be done. So that solve the problem, right?